# Recursion Code in C

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to write a code that checks how many of the of array `geusses` exist in the array `battelships`  **using recursion only** 
I cant understand why the function `checkCellsHit(int bships[],int lengthBS,int guesses[],int lengthG)` doesnt work.

the function `checkHit(int battleships[], int length, int guess)` works fine and checks if the number `guess` exist in `battelships`.

note that every users input ends with negativ number.
for instant:

```
Player 1 battleship locations:
0 5 10 2 3 4 7 -3
Player2 guesses:
11 12 13 -4
Battleship cells hit: 0
```

-

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #define MAX 200`

  int checkHit(int battleships[], int length, int guess){
    int value=0;
    if (battleships[0]<0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (battleships[0]==guess) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        value=checkHit((battleships+1), (length-1), guess);
        return value;
    }
  }

  int checkCellsHit(int bships[],int lengthBS,int guesses[],int lengthG){
    int count=0;
    if (bships[0]<0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (checkHit(bships, lengthBS, guesses[0])) {
        count++;
    }
    count=count+checkCellsHit(bships, lengthBS-1, guesses+1, lengthG-1);
    return count;
  }

  int main(){
    int battelships[MAX]={0}, guess[MAX]={0};
    int i=0,j=0, value;
    printf("Player1 battleship locations:\n");
    scanf("%d", &battelships[i]);
    for (i=1; battelships[i-1]>=0; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &battelships[i]);
    }
    printf("Player2 guesses::\n");
    scanf("%d", &guess[j]);
    for (j=1; battelships[j-1]>=0; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &guess[j]);
    }

    value=checkCellsHit(battelships, i, guess, j);

    printf("%d", value);

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: First do the recursion with a small and simple playing field on paper to see it it look okay. Then do the same but in a debugger, step through the function line by line, entering the recursive functions as they come along.

Comment: You're exit strategy for your check functions should include 0 or 1- **length** detection rather than valuation of the array content exclusively. As-presented *neither* function makes any use of the length parameter *at all*.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is in

```
count=count+checkCellsHit(bships, lengthBS-1, guesses+1, lengthG-1);
```

in `checkCellsHit` you go over the battel ships and the guesses.  the next step in you recursion you need to reduce the guesses NOT the battleships.

so change to the below code should fix it

```
count=count+checkCellsHit(bships, lengthBS, guesses+1, lengthG-1);
```